Change color of elements outside a region
Could you please help me achieve the following effect in svg.
The svg is generated dynamically by a web app, and contains various colored shapes. When the user selects a region within the svg, all the shapes (including parts of shapes) that are outside of the selected region, should change their color to the same shade of grey, as illustrated schematically on the following diagram:
Before selection:

With selection applied:

I do not want to use CSS filters, because I may need to be able to export this svg as a standalone image. So I thought svg filters; but I've been struggling to set them up.

Please add a minimal reproducible example. Please clarify, how the color change should be triggered. Quite likely you could opt for an element hover event and change the fill as needed. This would require your SVG to be inlined/injected to the DOM.

@herrstrietzel I have posted my example in a response below. I think it achieves the effect that I am after, although I am not at all experienced with composing svg filters.

Fair enough but It's not clear how you would change the selected filter area on user pointer events ...

@herrstrietzel Oh, I probably phrased my question poorly. I was only wondering about how to bulk-change the color of all shapes and fragments of shapes that are outside a given area within an svg. The area, in my particular case, is selected by the user pressing the mouse button and moving the cursor while inside the svg; but that particular bit of interactivity did not pose a problem to me.

Here is my own crude attempt at achieving this effect, which might do the job.
Initial svg:


<svg viewBox="0 0 900 400"
  style="width: 900px; height: 400px; border-style: dashed; border-width: 1px; border-color: black; width: 550px">
  <text x="410" y="100" font-size="30">Testing</text>
  <circle cx="450" cy="200" r="50" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="250" cy="200" r="30" fill="green" />
  <circle cx="750" cy="200" r="20" fill="blue" />
</svg>



Svg with the desired effect:


  <svg viewBox="0 0 900 400"
    style="width: 900px; height: 400px; border-style: dashed; border-width: 1px; border-color: black; width: 550px">
    <filter id="grayscale">
      <feFlood flood-color="#ccd3d8" flood-opacity="1" x="0" y="0" height="400" width="420" result="A"/>
      <feFlood flood-color="#ccd3d8" flood-opacity="1" x="475" y="0" height="400" width="420" result="D"/> 
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" in="D" result="C"/>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" in="A" result="B"/>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="B" />
        <feMergeNode in="C" />
      </feMerge>
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>

    <g filter="url(#grayscale)">
      <text x="410" y="100" font-size="30">Testing</text>
      <circle cx="450" cy="200" r="50" fill="red" />
      <circle cx="250" cy="200" r="30" fill="green" />
      <circle cx="750" cy="200" r="20" fill="blue" />
    </g>
  </svg>



